Azure OpenAI with AzureExtensionsOptions it does not inherent model's knowledge
In Azure OpenAI I have added my own Data Source and it's working fine if I ask question within my train data but if I ask something outside of my train data it does not give answer and It's looks like GPT model does not know anything about that question but when I remove my own data source then it gives me good answer.
Here is my ChatCompletionsOptions
    var chatCompletionOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions
    {
        Temperature = 0.7f,
        MaxTokens = 800,
        NucleusSamplingFactor = 0.95f,
        FrequencyPenalty = 0,
        PresencePenalty = 0,
        DeploymentName = _configuration["AzureAi:DeploymentName"]
    };

    chatCompletionOptions.AzureExtensionsOptions = new AzureChatExtensionsOptions
    {
        Extensions = {
            new AzureSearchChatExtensionConfiguration
            {
                SearchEndpoint = new Uri(_configuration["AzureSearch:Endpoint"]),
                VectorizationSource = new OnYourDataDeploymentNameVectorizationSource("text-embedding-ada-002"),
                IndexName = _configuration["AzureSearch:IndexName"],
                Authentication = new OnYourDataApiKeyAuthenticationOptions(_configuration["AzureSearch:ApiKey"]),
                QueryType = AzureSearchQueryType.VectorSimpleHybrid,
                ShouldRestrictResultScope = false
            }
        }
    };

    // Add the user query
    chatCompletionOptions.Messages.Add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, "Create a console application that can print 'Hello World'"));

    // Get the response from ChatGPT which includes the Azure Search results
    var response = await _openAIClient.ChatCompletionAsync(chatCompletionOptions);
    return response.Choices.FirstOrDefault()?.Message.Content;

GPT response is :

I'm sorry, but I couldn't find any information related to creating a console application that can print 'Hello World' in the retrieved documents . Could you please provide more context or information about what you're looking for?

But if I ask the same question without AzureSearchChatExtensionConfiguration then I get good result.
My question is how can I add my data on top of Model knowledge in azure OpenAI? or am I missing anything.

Model: gpt-35-turbo (0301)
Model: text-embedding-ada-002 (2)
SDK : Azure.AI.OpenAI (1.0.0-beta.17)

Thanks in advance.


My question is how can I add my data on top of Model knowledge in azure OpenAI? or am I missing anything.

Firstly, Check that the custom data is used to enhance the model's responses rather than replace its knowledge. The goal is to create a hybrid approach where the model can utilize both its pre-trained knowledge and the custom data.

Use the hybrid search configuration correctly so that the model can combine its general knowledge with the specific information retrieved from the data source.

var chatCompletionOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions
{
    Temperature = 0.7f,
    MaxTokens = 800,
    NucleusSamplingFactor = 0.95f,
    FrequencyPenalty = 0,
    PresencePenalty = 0,
    DeploymentName = _configuration["AzureAi:DeploymentName"]
};

chatCompletionOptions.AzureExtensionsOptions = new AzureChatExtensionsOptions
{
    Extensions = {
        new AzureSearchChatExtensionConfiguration
        {
            SearchEndpoint = new Uri(_configuration["AzureSearch:Endpoint"]),
            VectorizationSource = new OnYourDataDeploymentNameVectorizationSource("text-embedding-ada-002"),
            IndexName = _configuration["AzureSearch:IndexName"],
            Authentication = new OnYourDataApiKeyAuthenticationOptions(_configuration["AzureSearch:ApiKey"]),
            QueryType = AzureSearchQueryType.VectorSimpleHybrid,
            ShouldRestrictResultScope = false,
            TopK = 5 // Adjust as necessary
        }
    }
};

// Add the user query
chatCompletionOptions.Messages.Add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, "Create a console application that can print 'Hello World'"));

// Get the response from ChatGPT which includes the Azure Search results
var response = await _openAIClient.ChatCompletionAsync(chatCompletionOptions);
var content = response.Choices.FirstOrDefault()?.Message.Content;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content) || content.Contains("I couldn't find any information"))
{
    // Fall back to a query without Azure Search extension
    var fallbackOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions
    {
        Temperature = 0.7f,
        MaxTokens = 800,
        NucleusSamplingFactor = 0.95f,
        FrequencyPenalty = 0,
        PresencePenalty = 0,
        DeploymentName = _configuration["AzureAi:DeploymentName"]
    };

    fallbackOptions.Messages.Add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, "Create a console application that can print 'Hello World'"));
    response = await _openAIClient.ChatCompletionAsync(fallbackOptions);
    content = response.Choices.FirstOrDefault()?.Message.Content;
}

return content;

The QueryType = AzureSearchQueryType.VectorSimpleHybrid checks that both semantic (vector-based) and keyword-based searches are performed. This allows the model to retrieve the most relevant documents from the custom data.
Reference:

Use your own data with Azure OpenAI Service
Bring your own data to Azure OpenAI chat models
Azure Chat Completion models with your own data (preview)


I hit a similar issue and I finally figured it out.  If you dont provide a RoleInformation it seems like it only answers questions from the document.
In your code you have:
chatCompletionOptions.AzureExtensionsOptions = new AzureChatExtensionsOptions
{
    Extensions = {
        new AzureSearchChatExtensionConfiguration
        {
            SearchEndpoint = new Uri(_configuration["AzureSearch:Endpoint"]),
            VectorizationSource = new OnYourDataDeploymentNameVectorizationSource("text-embedding-ada-002"),
            IndexName = _configuration["AzureSearch:IndexName"],
            Authentication = new OnYourDataApiKeyAuthenticationOptions(_configuration["AzureSearch:ApiKey"]),
            QueryType = AzureSearchQueryType.VectorSimpleHybrid,
            ShouldRestrictResultScope = false
        }
    }
};

Add a property RoleInformation which gives extra context in what you want to do with the documents.
chatCompletionOptions.AzureExtensionsOptions = new AzureChatExtensionsOptions
{
    Extensions = {
        new AzureSearchChatExtensionConfiguration
        {
            SearchEndpoint = new Uri(_configuration["AzureSearch:Endpoint"]),
            VectorizationSource = new OnYourDataDeploymentNameVectorizationSource("text-embedding-ada-002"),
            IndexName = _configuration["AzureSearch:IndexName"],
            Authentication = new OnYourDataApiKeyAuthenticationOptions(_configuration["AzureSearch:ApiKey"]),
            QueryType = AzureSearchQueryType.VectorSimpleHybrid,
            ShouldRestrictResultScope = false,
            RoleInformation = "Your a system that helps users perform various tasks..." 
        }
    }
};

Once you add that you will see your ai answer questions that are not found in your document.
